# How to capture traffic with fiddler while using another proxy

Tags: proxy, fiddler

To access some websites that I need to test I need to plugin some specific proxies on firefox. However when I set my proxy through firefox or any browser, fiddler doesnt capture anymore request, due that it also uses its own proxy to get the requests. Is there any way I could capture traffic using fiddler while at the same time Im using an external proxy using any browser?

Answer (score 6):

Fiddler allows you to **chain** to an upstream proxy, so traffic first goes to Fiddler, then goes from Fiddler to another proxy.

Fiddler will automatically chain to any proxy configured in Internet Explorer.

To manually chain to a different proxy, in Fiddler, click Tools > Fiddler Options and go to the **Gateway** tab. Specify the desired upstream proxy there.

Comment: This is very useful info