# Fiddler not capturing connections via proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, fiddler

I have a C# program with some connections made via some external proxy.

Fiddler is not able to capture these requests which do not use fiddler as a proxy

Is there any way to make these connections go via fiddler first in any C# way or fiddler settings way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576947/how-to-capture-traffic-with-fiddler-while-using-another-proxy Don't use proxy in your code

Comment: I dont just use one proxy in my code, this fiddler setting can not give me the flexibility which I had in C# coding. But it is one good suggestion. Thank you

Comment: You can also use FiddlerCore in your code and chain the proxies programmatically

Comment: I just googled. Do I need to implement the UI myself to make it as easy to debug traffic as fiddler?

Comment: Yes..Better write to file....

Comment: Although its too time consuming for me to implement. It is a good answer to my question. Please answer my question and I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FiddlerCore and chain the proxies..

```
Proxy p = new Proxy(new List<string>() { "122.129.107.3:8080" }); //real proxies...

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1", 8888); //local proxy(fiddler core)
wc.Headers["User-Agent"] = "SO/1.0";
var html = wc.DownloadString("http://google.com");
```

---

```
public class Proxy
{
    List<string> _Proxies = null;
    public Proxy(List<string> proxies)
    {
        _Proxies = proxies;
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest;
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, false, true);
    }

    static long _Sequence = 0;
    void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Fiddler.Session oSession)
    {
        var sequence = Interlocked.Increment(ref _Sequence);
        string proxy = _Proxies[(int)(sequence % _Proxies.Count)];

        oSession["x-OverrideGateway"] = proxy;

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Proxy[{0}]> {1}", proxy, oSession.host));
    }
}
```

Just pass a list of proxies to this class. It will use a different one for each request. Your client will use only this *Proxy* class

Comment: very detailed solution

Comment: There's no need to use FiddlerCore for this; you can use Fiddler itself. Set `x-OverrideGateway` inside Rules > Customize Rules > `OnBeforeRequest`.

Comment: @EricLaw If you look at the code, it changes the proxy with every request (see the constructors parameters `List<string> proxies`). Can you do that with fiddler? BTW: this has already been  discussed in comments above.

Comment: Of course you can do that with Fiddler itself; put the code inside the `OnBeforeRequest` function as described.

Comment: @EricLaw Thank you Eric. Seems no need to continue this meaningless discussion.