.NET Aspire host does not start when using Fiddler
I have here a project with a dotnet core api and mysql database and few other components, all orchestrated together with .NET Aspire and hosted with Podman containers. Everything runs smoothly untill I try to capture traffic using Telerik Fiddler. Then this error appears in console on host startup:

info: Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.dcpctrl.ServiceReconciler[0]
could not use the same port for all addresses associated with requested service address, service will be reachable only using
specific IP address {"ServiceName": {"name":"mysql"},
"Reconciliation": 6, "AttemptedCommonPort": 3308,
"RequestedServiceAddress": "localhost"} fail:
Aspire.Hosting.Dcp.dcpctrl.ServiceReconciler[0]
could not start the proxy {"ServiceName": {"name":"mysql"}, "Reconciliation": 6, "error": "could not start the proxy for the
service: listen tcp [::1]:3308: bind: Only one usage of each socket
address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted."}

Similar error indicating conflict of ports appears for every component of the application. The error seems to say that something is already running on the same port but this is not something I can see. Once Fiddler is shutdown, everything comes back to normal.
Am I missing some setting in Fiddler or the project?

Fiddler registers as System Proxy when started. Maybe your setup uses another proxy already and the proxy chaining does not work?
@ericlaw wrote about Fiddler proxy chaining here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18576947/how-to-capture-traffic-with-fiddler-while-using-another-proxy
